# How do I make my React App secure? As of now I can login using React DOM Tools, what am I missing?

Tags: reactjs, security, authentication

I am currently learning by doing. So I've created the backend using FeathersJS and am authenticating through the endpoint just fine. When the user gets authenticated I set the 'isLoggedIn' state to true and then pass that along to other components to make sure that the user is logged in so they can access that component.

Now when I see and test it using the REACT DOM Tools, I can see that I can just login by clicking on isLoggedIn and it will give me access to my app bypassing the whole login system.

What is the correct way to create a login setup? Can the isLoggedIn state be hidden somehow? Please help!

I've been looking around for information on how to do this but I haven't found anything that useful yet..

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdyiU.jpg)

Comment: Front-ends are not securable. The react app you write, meaning the javascript inside the html page, is executed on someone's browser that they control. the only important thing security wise is that people cannot access YOUR server data without proper credentials. client / front end - NOT YOURS. backend, database etc YOURS. that being said your front end should have a good user experience and not fool anyone thinking they can access stuff without logging in and getting the proper credentials first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of [session cookies](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/01/08/web-security-session-cookies/). Or I often find myself using [Passport.js](http://www.passportjs.org/). But of course this implys that you have control over the server and database.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I will try it with the passport, feathersJS is already authenticating through it. Thank you!